# profiling akka dispatchers

Tags: scala, akka, jprofiler

I am looking at akka application using jprofiler.
can someone please explain how to read it and what can we deduct from such image ?
[image]

Comment: Any chance to see code samples? sure this could help

Comment: This is a production code plus it is scattered.  So unfortunately I cannot share it.

Comment: Maybe this section of the Akka docs could help: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html#problem-blocking-on-default-dispatcher